# How to configure multi language response of aws amplify?

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, aws-amplify

I am using amazon AWS [amplify](https://aws-amplify.github.io/). I am getting all the success and error responses in the english language. I want to configure multi language so that I can receive error message and response in the respective language.I was tried I18n with in amplify. But it is not working. Do I need to configure anything in the cognito ?

Comment: Did you follow the below documentation https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/i18n https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/i18n.html

Comment: I did I18n.setLanguage('fr'). I thought aws response will be in french. Did I understand correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

## putVocabularies()

You can create your custom dictionary and set it as your vocabularies in your app. Dictionary is a JavaScript object that you can implement with different terms and languages.

```
const dict = {
    'fr': {
        'Sign In': "Se connecter",
        'Sign Up': "S'inscrire"
    },
    'es': {
        'Sign In': "Registrarse",
        'Sign Up': "Regístrate"
    }
};

I18n.putVocabularies(dict);
```

## get()

Retrieves a phrase from the dictionary for the active language. If the phrase does not have an entry in the dictionary, the original parameter value will be returned.

```
I18n.get('Sign In');
```

Comment: I am not concern about how to handle client locale setup. How do I get aws response error messages in different lanuages ? I am using AWS cognito

Comment: At present, AWS returns error messages only in English.

Comment: Is it possible to set the language and aws amplify ui will use the dictionary for the default authenticator ui?